# TypeScript Generics Problem using "infer" when a type is deduced from function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the process of learning TypeScript I'm trying to create a function that will deduce the return value from the input parameter as a dictionary with values defined as function objects with propper types.

Originally this is taken from [frida types library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/frida-gum/index.d.ts#L1637).

I am attempting to extend with a feature to define an API of functions.

The problem I'm facing which I can ilustrate in a small snippet is that when passing the type directly to another generic type the infer keyword seems to work, **but when the type is deduced from the function argument everything breaks.**

I have the following code snippet with minimum code to illustrate the problem

```
declare class Pointer {}

type NativeTypesMap = {
  int: number;
  long: number;
  void: void;
  pointer: Pointer;
};

type ValuesOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type KeysOf<T> = keyof T;

type NativeTypesValue = ValuesOf<NativeTypesMap>;
type NativeTypesType = KeysOf<NativeTypesMap>;

type GetValue<Map, Type, T extends Type> = T extends keyof Map ? Map[T] : never;

type GetArgValue<T extends NativeTypesType> = GetValue<
  NativeTypesMap,
  NativeTypesType,
  T
>;

type Def<T extends NativeTypesType> = { r: T };

type DefAny = Def<any>;

declare type BaseApi = {
  [k: string]: DefAny;
};

type ApiCalls<T extends BaseApi> = {
  [p in keyof T]: T[p] extends Def<infer R>
    ? (...args: any) => GetArgValue<R>
    : never;
};

function createapi<T extends BaseApi>(params: T): ApiCalls<T> {
  // implementation omitted
  return {} as ApiCalls<T>;
}

type z = ApiCalls<{
  open: { r: "int" };
  malloc: { r: "pointer" };
  free: { r: "void" };
}>;
/*
 * z is calculated to be
 * type z = {
 *     open: (...args: any) => number;
 *     malloc: (...args: any) => Pointer;
 *     free: (...args: any) => void;
 * }
 */

var a = createapi({
  open: { r: "int" },
  malloc: { r: "pointer" },
  free: { r: "void" },
});
type c = typeof a;
/*
 * calculated type of a is:
 * tyoepf a = {
 *     open: never;
 *     malloc: never;
 *     free: never;
 * }
 */
```

[TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3P3m)

my goal is to change createapi such that the dedcued type of a would be the same as z.

Anyone has a clue what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the type of the object that you are passing into the function:

```
// const obj: {
//   open: {
//       r: string;
//   };
//   malloc: {
//       r: string;
//   };
//   free: {
//       r: string;
//   };
// }
const obj = {
  open: { r: 'int' },
  malloc: { r: 'pointer' },
  free: { r: 'void' },
}
```

The compiler widens the type to primitives, to make our life easier when we are working with variables. Since `obj` no longer has literal values in its properties, your `infer` condition doesn't work anymore.

There are two approaches to fix the problem:

[const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) - prevents typescript from widening the type:

```
// const obj: {
//   readonly open: {
//       readonly r: "int";
//   };
//   readonly malloc: {
//       readonly r: "pointer";
//   };
//   readonly free: {
//       readonly r: "void";
//   };
// }
const obj = {
  open: { r: 'int' },
  malloc: { r: 'pointer' },
  free: { r: 'void' },
} as const
```

Testing:

```
// {
//   readonly open: (...args: any) => number;
//   readonly malloc: (...args: any) => Pointer;
//   readonly free: (...args: any) => void;
// }
var a = createapi({
  open: { r: 'int' },
  malloc: { r: 'pointer' },
  free: { r: 'void' },
} as const);
```

Looks good, however, it can get quite annoying and inconvenient to add `as const` to every function invocation. And in `Typescript 5.0` the [const type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) were added, which are doing the same thing what *const assertion* does over the function parameters:

```
function createapi<const T extends BaseApi>(params: T): ApiCalls<T> {
  // implementation omitted
  return {} as ApiCalls<T>;
}

// {
//   readonly open: (...args: any) => number;
//   readonly malloc: (...args: any) => Pointer;
//   readonly free: (...args: any) => void;
// }
var a = createapi({
  open: { r: 'int' },
  malloc: { r: 'pointer' },
  free: { r: 'void' },
});
```